# Entity Framework issue when creating unit tests

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing

I am specifically getting the following error:

"The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid."

```
[TestMethod()]
        public void salesOrderFillListTest()
        {
            SalesOrderController_Accessor target = new SalesOrderController_Accessor(); 
            string orderNumber = "1954120";

            SalesOrderData result;
            result = target.FillingOrder(orderNumber);
            Assert.AreEqual(null, result.ErrorMessage);
            Assert.AreEqual(32, result.LineItems.Count);
            Assert.AreEqual("WRA-24-NFL-CLEV", result.LineItems[7].ItemNumber);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, result.LineItems[7].OrderQuantity);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, result.LineItems[7].FillingFilledQty);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, result.LineItems[7].FillingRemainQty);
        }
```

The error is coming up on the line:

```
result = target.FillingOrder(orderNumber);
```

I'm a junior developer and haven't had much experience with the many possible causes for this error. My App.config page contains the appropriate connection strings. Any ideas where to look for this one?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the full connection string in the app.settings file of the test project?

Comment: I would like to point out that if your tests are running against a database, you are not really doing unit testing. Instead you're using integration testing. Real unit tests don't have any dependencies and can be executed really fast. I blogged about this some time ago: http://wouterdekort.blogspot.nl/2012/03/unit-testing-hell-or-heaven.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully run tests found in another test project in the same solution. After looking more carefully I found that there were a few differences between the two connection strings in each project. The data in the failing test project had become antiquated. I updated the connection string and error resolved.

Thanks.